# Changing attributes of an object under conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, array.prototype.map

I want to change the values of an attribute under certain conditions as explained in the code below, but i don't want to use for cycles. I think that .map() can be useful but I don't know how.
Here is the (working) sample code:

```
class Replace {
    constructor(){
        this.Numbers = [
            {number:'1', feature:'A'},
            {number:'2', feature:'B'},
            {number:'2', feature:'C'},
            {number:'3', feature:'D'},
        ]
    }

    ReplaceNumbersWithWords (){
        for(this.i=0;this.i<this.Numbers.length;this.i++)
        if(this.Numbers[this.i].number==='1'){
            this.Numbers[this.i].number='one'
        }
        else if (this.Numbers[this.i].number==='2'){
            this.Numbers[this.i].number='two'
        }
        else if (this.Numbers[this.i].number==='3'){
            this.Numbers[this.i].number='three'
        }
        console.log(this.Numbers)
    }
}

const replace = new Replace()
replace.ReplaceNumbersWithWords()
```

As you can see, I want to change the attribute "number" of every object that is in the array "this.Numbers", how can in the most efficient way possible (without using for loops)?

The output must be:

```
[
  { number: 'one', feature: 'A' },
  { number: 'two', feature: 'B' },
  { number: 'two', feature: 'C' },
  { number: 'three', feature: 'D' }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is a kind of mapping that you are looking for

```js
class Replace {
  constructor() {
    this.Numbers = [
      { number: '1', feature: 'A' },
      { number: '2', feature: 'B' },
      { number: '2', feature: 'C' },
      { number: '3', feature: 'D' }
    ];

    this.mapRef = [
      { key: '1', value: 'one' },
      { key: '2', value: 'two' },
      { key: '3', value: 'three' }
    ];
  }

  ReplaceNumbersWithWords() {
    const newArr = this.Numbers.map(item => {
      return {
        number: this.mapRef.find(num => num.key === item.number).value,
        feature: item.feature
      };
    });
    console.log(newArr);
  }
}

const replace = new Replace();
replace.ReplaceNumbersWithWords();
```